# Flutter: tried to access method sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters(Ljava/security/Provider;)Ljava/security/AlgorithmParameters

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Started to get this error after updating the Android Studio to the latest version (4.0.1) and running `flutter build appbundle` to generate the aab:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                    
* What went wrong:                                                      
tried to access method sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters(Ljava/security/Provider;)Ljava/security/AlgorithmParameters; from class sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 962ms
```

Comment: Do you have another solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this particular issue was not related to Android Studio update or `flutter build appbundle`.

The error message does not have enough info about the issue, but after double-checking configs, I noticed that `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` values were no longer pointing to `29`.

Setting both `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 29 fixed the issue.

Comment: I done set `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 29, but Still have problem.